# Escape * in batch script

Tags: batch-file, count, arguments

I am trying to get the count of the passed arguments in my batch script. I found the appropriate answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/901966/593397). It worked flawlessly until I passed an argument with a star(*) in it.

**argcount.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)

echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do echo %%i- "!argVec[%%i]!"
```

**Usage:**

`argcount abc def ghi`

This gives me `3` args: `abc, def, ghi`

`argcount abc def *ghi jkl`

This also gives me `3` args: `abc, def, jkl`

Where I should get `4` args: `abc def *ghi jkl`

**Question**

How can I get the actual argument count along with the starred argument?

Comment: Can you call your script with `argcount abc def "*ghi" jkl` ?

Comment: @dee-see doesn't help. `for` interprets `*ghi` as a file mask and as there are no matching files, nothing is returned.

Comment: You could try a look at [dostips: foolproof counting of arguments](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2836)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` is designed to loop over files, so the strings in the `in` clause are supposed to be file names or file masks.
When there is no such file name, the string is processed as string, but as soon as a wildcard (`*` or `?`) is involved, that changes: The list is expanded with all matching file names (you don't have files matching `*ghi`, so the list remains empty - Try the same with `*.bat` ...).
So (as elegant as it may be), a `for` loop isn't what you need. Instead loop over your arguments in a loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set argCount=0
:loop
   if "%~1" == "" goto :done
   set /A argCount+=1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%~1"
   shift
goto :loop
:done
echo Number of processed arguments: %argCount%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%argCount%) do echo %%i- "!argVec[%%i]!"
```

Comment: You beat me by seconds, had the very same batch with just a label `:cont` for your `:done` ;-) (+1)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Got it. Also, many thanks for the explanation!