# Parse variable number of options and a file name from command line into two batch variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following command line in Windows CMD to run a batch program which needs to pass the paramters and the filename to another program called within the batch file:

```
mysample.bat -parm1=7 -parm2="abc" -parm3 myfile
```

My goal is to parse the command line and wind up with two variables `%options%` and `%filename%`.
where `%options%` contains the parameters as they are entered on the command line and where `%filename%` contains the filename.

The two variables should contain the following (from my sample command line above):
`%options%`  to contain `-parm1=7 -parm2="abc" -parm3
%filename%` with `filename` to contain `myfile`

I have tried variations of the `for` loop, but to no avail.  I have searched for examples here and other places, but found nothing that produces what I need.

Can anyone offer a clear, robust way of doing this in a batch program?  Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comments, I assume you need to loop through each argument and set all to options, so using `%*` we capture all of the arguments.

```
for %%i in (%*) do echo %%~i
```

As for your requirement, if you will have filename as the last argument each time, then here is an option:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for %%i in (%*) do set "filename=%%~i")>nul
set "options=%*"
set "options=!options:%filename%=!"
echo %options% %filename%
```

Comment: That's what I want, but I need the batch program to parse the command line, not issue hard-coded SET commands (refer to sample command line above).

mysample.bat
@echo off
.
.

... parse command line ... (this is the code I'm looking for)

echo %options%
echo %filename%

Comment: how should the batch file know what to pass? It is unclear what you need.

Comment: The parameters and file name need to come from %1 %2 %3 etc, etc, but there can be a variable number of parameters before the file name.

Comment: `%*` will take any/all arguments you give it i.e `mysample.bat %*` you would then need to loop through it and use each argument based on whatever you need to do.

Comment: You cannot escape a quote once you have an opening quote - the next quote will always close the quoting. So the first caret become part of the value of `options`. Better to use `set ^"options=parm1=7 -parm2="abc" -parm3 %filename%^"`. Either way, it isn't what the OP is looking for, but the quoting rules are kind of important to get right.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks. I did update the answer based on the OP comments.

Comment: `=` is parsed as a delimiter. That's probably the reason, parameter syntax is mostly used like `param value` or `param:value`

Comment: @Stephan whitespace are default delimeters, `=` needs to be specified as a delimeter so in this case it would set `%options%` with value of `-parm1=7 -parm2="abc" -parm3`... unless I am getting you comment incorrectly?

Comment: @Gerhard try `test.bat one=two` with a batch file like `echo %1 and %2` (parameter parsing is different from `for` parsing). `%*` takes "all parameters" unparsed. Disassembling them with a `for` loop [also has it's quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889432/escape-in-batch-script)

Comment: Thank you Gerhard.  Your solution gives me the results I am after, as long as the characters in filename do not appear in any of the parameter values (which is very unlikely).

Comment: Follow-up question: What is the correct syntax to test character 1 in each parameter for NOT '-'?

Here is what I tried, using substring syntax with %%~1: (for %%i in (%*) do if not %%~1:~0,1%=='-' set "filename=%%~i")>nul

But this give the error message: The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~i")>nul